# Karate call read feature failing with reference error

Tags: karate

I am trying to invoke a feature for each element of json array

```
        * def values = karate.mapWithKey(values, 'value')
        * def result = call read('my-feature') values
```

My feature is defined as

```
@Ignore
Feature: My feature
  Background:
    *some task

   Scenario:
    # TEST: My scenario
    Given path urlPath, value
```

This works fine if i use @Tags and only run this scenario.

But on trying to run all karate tests, this fails with error

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: my-feature.feature:15 - javascript evaluation failed: value, ReferenceError: "value" is not defined in  at line number 1

How do i fix this?
I have marked the ignored feature as @Ignore, but that doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution ,
I was using @Ignore annotation but it also need to be mapped at APITest class
Defining
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@Ignore"})

And marking the feature file as @Ignore, solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
* def result = call read('my-feature') ids
```

If still stuck, follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: yeah that's a typo in trying to move test to generic values, but the issue was the called feature was not being ignored.

Comment: @varkashy I have no further ideas. follow the process please

Comment: yeah this got resolved, i posted the answer above.. thank you